# Div Disrupting My CSS Menu

Tags: css, html

I thought I had perfected my CSS navigation bar in Code Pen, but when I implemented it in my actual layout, it seems that the other divs in my layout disrupt the drop downs (the drop down appears, but when I move the mouse to select one of the children, the dropdown disappears).

Here is the code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cKJlu

And here it is implemented on my site: http://www.onedirectionconnection.com/tester

And here's the CSS:

```
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.main-navigation li:last-of-type{
    margin-right:0;
}
.main-navigation a {
  text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #269BA9;
    width: 130px;
    color: #fff;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
        top: 1.5em;
        left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
}
.main-navigation li:hover > a {
  background-color: #DA5969;
}
.main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {
}
.main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation li.current_page_item a,
.main-navigation li.current-menu-item a {
}

/* Small menu */
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

If anyone could help me figure out what the issue is, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is space between the sub-menu and your menu. The cause of it is that you have given the submenu a `top: 1.5em;`. If there is space between it you are not hovering over it anymore.

```
.main-navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    float: left; // remove this, float does not work with position: absolute
    position: absolute;
        top: 1.5em; // culprit of your problem
        left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

and give .main-navigation a `float: left;` to solve the margin problem.

Comment: You're welcome. Click on the checkmark pls as it has solved your problem.

Comment: I was just waiting for the 5 min limit to end! Checked it! :-) Thanks again.

Comment: don't forget to give .main-navigation a `float:left;` to solve the margin problem